# Omitir comas y corchetes [ ]

Tags: java

```
   s = [1,2,(8+5)*2]
```

Lo que quiero conseguir que la expresión de arriba separarla por comas , y quitarle el corchete abierto y cerrado , y quedarme solo con las expresiones que hay entre cada coma. Hasta el momento he hecho un ***split*** por la coma de ese array , pero después de ello no sé omitir los corchetes

```
s.split(",");
```

pero cuando hago

```
s.split("[");
```

me lanza error.

¿Alguna sugerencia?

**Edit:**
He probado también esto:

```
            String[] arrayExpresion = expresion.split(",");
            String str = String.join(" ", arrayExpresion);
            String[] arrayExpresion2 = str.split("]");
            String str2 = String.join(" ", arrayExpresion);
            String[] arrayExpresion3 = str2.split("[");
```

Comment: No tienes en java alguna librería para deserializar json? Esa cadena tuya es un objeto, pero en formato json. Con deserializarlo obtienes cada elemento en un array...

Comment: Buenas , no es un objeto JSON . Estoy haciendo procesamiento del lenguaje natural con distintas expresiones , vamos diría que la opción que dices no vale..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

NOTA: Al escribir la pregunta, deberías dar los detalles de qué error te sale.

Yendo a tu problema, si miramos el [javadoc de String.split(String)](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#split(java.lang.String)):

> Splits this string around matches of the given regular expression.

Es decir, interpreta lo que le pasas como una expresión regular. "[" lo interpreta como parte de una expresión (p.ej. "[A-Z]"), no como el literal corchete.

Para que lo interprete como literal y no como un símbolo de la expresión regular, hay que "escapar" el símbolo:

```
str.split("\\[");
```

Comment: No está de más que te familiarices con expresiones regulares. Un ejemplo con corchetes o comas sería `"\\[|\\]|,", o "[\\[\\],]"

Comment: Aunque te he dado la respuesta por buena y me ha servido ,  me gustaría que me explicases más a fondo éste último ejemplo que has puesto con expresiones regulares , si es posible , claro. No estoy muy familiarizado aún con regexp

Comment: Básicamente, las dos expresiones indican "literal [ o literal ] o ,". `split` partirá el string por las partes que hagan "match" con la expresión regular.